# Can a dash plot extend below the height of the page (perhaps using scrolling)?

Tags: plotly-dash, plotly-python

I have this script of plotting using dash (the slider in the top does not work- no problem)

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import random
    
# Generate random data for the scatter plot
random.seed(42)
num_points = 100
x_data = [random.uniform(-5, 5) for _ in range(num_points)]
y_data = [random.uniform(-10, 5) for _ in range(num_points)]

frame_min=1
frame_max=25410

dist= (frame_max+1-frame_min)//5

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
   

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.H1("nothing"),
    
    # RangeSlider for selecting the range of 'fr' values
    html.Div([
        html.Label("Select a Range of  Values:"),
        dcc.RangeSlider(
            id="fr-range",
            min=frame_min,
            max=frame_max,
            step=1,
            marks={i: str(i) for i in range(frame_min, frame_max+1, dist)},
            value=[frame_min, frame_max],
        ),
        html.Div(id='range-display')
    ]),
 
    dcc.Graph(id='scatter-plot-1', config={'displayModeBar': False}, style={'width': '100%', 'display': 'inline-block', 'height': '800px'}),
       

])

@app.callback(
    [Output('scatter-plot-1', 'figure'), Output('range-display', 'children')],
    [Input('fr-range', 'value')]
)
def update_plots(range_value):
    min_value, max_value = range_value
    
    fig1 = go.Figure(
        data=go.Scatter(
        x=x_data,
        y=y_data,
        mode="markers",
        marker=dict(size=3),
    ))

    fig1.update_layout(title_text='SOme plot')

    fig1.update_xaxes(title="Left ")
    fig1.update_yaxes(title="Right ")
    # fig1.update_xaxes(minallowed=-10,maxallowed=10) #this destroys the proportions
    fig1.update_xaxes(scaleanchor="y", scaleratio=1)
    fig1.update_yaxes(scaleanchor="x", scaleratio=1)

    # fig1.update_xaxes(minallowed=-10,maxallowed=10)  #this breaks the square

    selected_range_text = f"Selected Range: {min_value} to {max_value}"


    return fig1,selected_range_text 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

This gives this result

[image]

which is fine. But notice that there is  unused space in the left and right part of the plot. And I would like for X to go  from -10 to 10 ***but keeping the scales***  (the commented line destroys the proportions)
In order to do that I realize that the Y axis has to extend way beyond the limits of the page so some scrolling might be necessary

Is this possible?